# SQL Query - Outstanding Payments

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query to retrieve outstanding payments from the database, which is the total invoice amount minus the total payment amount. The problem is though, when there are no payments against the invoice, these just don't show up. I want those invoice amounts to show up, with their total payment amount being zero. Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Client.FirstName + ' ' + Client.LastName                   AS
                [Client Name],
                SUM(Invoices.InvoiceAmount)                                AS
                [Total Invoice Amounts],
                SUM(ClientPayments.PaymentAmount)                          AS
                [Total Amount Paid],
                SUM(Invoices.InvoiceAmount - ClientPayments.PaymentAmount) AS
                [Outstanding Payment Amount]
FROM   Invoices
       INNER JOIN ClientPayments
         ON Invoices.InvoiceNumberID = ClientPayments.InvoiceNumberID
       INNER JOIN Client
         ON Invoices.ClientNumberID = Client.ClientNumberID
GROUP  BY Client.FirstName,
          Client.LastName
```

Thanks,
Amy

Comment: which SQL... SQL Server, MySQL, ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably is based on doing a left join, but would you get bogus results if you have one invoice that has been paid multiple times (partial payments).  Would those "Sum" equations count the invoice amount TWICE ex: One for each partial payment?  I would try as follows.

```
SELECT 
      C.ClientNumberID,
      C.FirstName + ' ' + C.LastName AS ClientName, 
      SUM( I.InvoiceAmount ) TotalInvoices, 
      SUM( CP.PaymentAmount ) AS TotalAmountPaid, 
      SUM( I.InvoiceAmount ) - SUM( CP.PaymentAmount ) AS OutstandingPaymentAmount
   FROM
      Invoices I
         JOIN Clients C
            on I.ClientNumberID = C.ClientNumberID

      LEFT JOIN ClientPayments CP
         on I.InvoiceNumberID = CP.InvoiceNumberID
   GROUP BY
      I.ClientNumberID
   ORDER BY
      C.LastName,
      C.FirstName
```

Notice my GROUP BY is by the client number...  What would happen otherwise, if you had 5 customers "William Smith", or "Robert Brown" which could be considered a "common name".  You don't want to give one William Smith a statement that said he owed $5000 when he paid in full on all his purchases, while the invoices were actually split among other "William Smith" customers.  THEN, the ORDER BY will put them into whatever order you need... or based on Outstanding amount descending for biggest collections at the top.

Comment: 1 ex. : `GROUP BY I.ClientNumberID` and then 'SELECT C.ClientNumberID' ?

Comment: 2 ex.: What if one invoice (amount 1000) has two payments (50 and 800)? SUM(InvoiceAmount) - SUM(PaymentAmount) = (1000 + 1000) - (50+800) = 2000 - 850 = 1150 (wrong) instead of 150 (ok)

Comment: 3 ex.: `GROUP BY I.ClientNumberID` and then `SELECT c.FirstName + ' ' + ...` ?

Comment: @Amy, although you have accepted my answer as the solution, I didn't actually try the query to ensure the scenario presented by Bogdan as noted above... Can you please confirm that my SUM() instances are working correctly in the case of a single invoice with multiple partial payments against it?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` for the first join in your query

Comment: Okay cool, it's bringing up the names of the people who haven't paid anything, but Total Payment Amount is null and so is Outstanding Amount. How would I make Total Payment Amount show zeros and the Outstanding Amount be the full amount of the invoice? (so Invoice Amount - 0 = Outstanding amount)?

Comment: If you're using T-SQL (MS SQL Server) you may use `ISNULL` function for this. So the first part of query will look like: `SELECT DISTINCT 
                  Client.FirstName + ' ' + Client.LastName AS [Client Name], SUM(Invoices.InvoiceAmount) AS [Total Invoice Amounts], ISNULL(SUM(ClientPayments.PaymentAmount), 0) 
                  AS [Total Amount Paid], ISNULL(SUM(Invoices.InvoiceAmount - ClientPayments.PaymentAmount) , SUM(Invoices.InvoiceAmount))AS [Outstanding Payment Amount]`